# Chrome extension as static server

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I would like to make a chrome extension that simply serve static content from a defined directory.  As usual the static directory will be in the extension repository.

I would like the extension to open in a complete tab.  For example, my grease-monkey extension opena a tab with a url that starts with `chrome-extension://`.  The tab is this requirement that blocks me.

Someone know an example of such a plugin?  A *hello world* in a new tab extension would fit my needs.

Comment: Probably duplicate with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251008/chrome-extension-to-open-link-in-new-tab-no-error-but-does-nothing-on-click?rq=1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359608/chrome-tabs-update-redirects-to-chrome-extension-invalid

Comment: thanks, I'll look at it and close the question as duplicate if it answer my question

Comment: Actually, the linked question is not exactly the same.  Bellow answer is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Extension page inside a tab

This is pretty easy to achieve: all you have to do is to create a basic extension with a folder containing the `page.html` and the relative JavaScript and CSS files; then you can use the [`chrome.tabs`API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) to create a new tab and display the `page.html` inside it.

### Implementation

Following these steps, you'll be able to open a new tab containing a page hosted in your extension folder, which will have an URL like `chrome-extension://<id>/page/page.html`:

1. Create an extension and the relative files for the manifest, background and the page you want to display. The extension's directory should then look like this:

   ```
   <root/>:
     - background.js
     - manifest.json
     - <page/>:
         - page.html
         - page.js
         - page.css
   ```
2. Create a simple `manifest.json` file declaring the background page:

   ```
   {
       "manifest_version": 2,
       "name": "Some test",
       "version": "0",

       "background": {
           "scripts": ["/background.js"] 
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create the `background.js` script, where you will create the tab:

   ```
   chrome.tabs.create({url: "/page/page.html"});
   ```
4. Create the `page.html` file, which is just a regular html page:

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
       <head>
           <title>Test</title>
           <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="page.css"/>
       </head>
       <body>
           <script src="page.js"></script>
       </body>
   </html>
   ```
5. Create the `page.js` script, which will run inside your `page.html`, and where you can do whatever you want:

   ```
   var h = document.createElement('h1');

   h.textContent = 'Hello World!';
   document.body.appendChild(h);
   ```

### Result

The result of the above will be something like this:

[image: result]

Comment: The "tabs" permission is not required for the create method.

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted.  Many thanks!  chrome extensions rocks